# Can I set up shortcut keys for commonly used words?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Can I set up my own shortcuts for alt keys for frequently used words?

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but it sounds like you want to setup universal keyboard macros / hotkeys.  If so, you'll probably be able to do what you want using AutoHotkey.  See: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: We used to use this at my old work. Works great!